# Apache POI 3.9 generated Excel XSSF has ? in place of special characters like á (Spanish) in weblogic

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, apache-poi, weblogic, xssf

I am working on an APP in which I have to generate EXCEL with `XSSFCellStyle`, etc. I am using Apache POI 3.9.

In some field I am doing this:

```
cell.setValue(myString);
```

`myString` may contains special characters like `ñ` and `á`, which are Spanish. These characters may come from `i18n.properties`, or hardcoded as plain String.

```
myString = "ññññññññ";
```

All is well in local machine with Tomcat8, but in Weblogic server, in the Excel generated, I see ´?` in place of these characters.

I read somewhere that in Weblogic servers the default charset is `UTF-8`. The local environment is of Spanish(cp1252), and in Eclipse Luna the workspace charset is also `cp1252`, so it may be the reason, but I am not sure. Should I change in `Preference - Workspace`, or in JVM parameters `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`?

I also read about Apache POI encoding handling, that the API handles it all, so I am not to worry about that. All I can do is set font charset, like this:

```
font.setCharSet(FontCharset.DEFAULT);
```

But, I cannot see `UTF-8` here. In source code I see:

```
/**
 * Charset represents the basic set of characters associated with a font (that it can display), and 
 * corresponds to the ANSI codepage (8-bit or DBCS) of that character set used by a given language. 
 * 
 * @author Gisella Bronzetti
 */
public enum FontCharset {

 ANSI(0),
 DEFAULT(1),
 SYMBOL(2),
 MAC(77),
 SHIFTJIS(128),
 HANGEUL(129),
 JOHAB(130),
 GB2312(134),
 CHINESEBIG5(136),
 GREEK(161),
 TURKISH(162),
 VIETNAMESE(163),
 HEBREW(177),
 ARABIC(178),
 BALTIC(186),
 RUSSIAN(204),
 THAI(222),
 EASTEUROPE(238),
 OEM(255);
```

Neither that of `WESTEUROPE`. So how can I set it?

Comment: Java itself and via that Apache POI handle strings as Unicode. So as long as you put in the correct data, it should handle them correctly without any encoding-setting. I would first check that the data is actually coming in correctly on the WebLogic server, e.g. by doing a hexdump of the String.getBytes("UTF-16") and verifying that you get the same as locally...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @centic for the hint. I finally find my solution:

- Change JVM encoding by settting parameter `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, or,
- Change text file encoding to `UTF-8` for my project in Eclipse.

Thus special characters hard-coded in Strings will be converted to `?` and I manually fixed them and save the `.java` as `UTF-8` (now is default), and compile the project and make my WAR. Now in Weblogic it's all fine.

I think the problem lies in that in local machine, my java files are encoded as `cp1252` according to JVM and Eclipse settings, and then in Tomcat, as in the same environment, also has `cp1252` as its decoding setting(both inherited from my Windows 7), so it's ok. But in Weblogic, it only accepts UTF-8 as input, and therefore will only decode my WAR/class files using UTF-8, so characters encoded as `cp1252` are not recognized.